Returning a value from column of the last row of entry sheet, if a value is less than another value in
Below I am summarizing a step by step process on what I am looking to do:

This screenshot shows where I am entering the data (the sheet is called Entry_Sheet, in this problem, I am focusing on the "Exhibition" type of products, in particular the table. You can see in the screenshot that John Smith has taken the last available table out of stock.

This screenshot shows another sheet, where the data that is being entered is stored into a more readable format. The area in question here is the "Locators" cell column.
What I am wanting to do is that if the "Quantity @YBS" is less than Quantity Total by 1, then look at the Entry_Sheet at the last time that stock was removed on this particular object, then copy the name of the "Used By" column, so I know that the stock that was removed was taken by this person.
I would like to do for multiple products too, so if there is the difference of the "Quantity @YBS" is 2, then look at the Entry_Sheet for the last 2 rows where stock was removed, and then show 2 names in the "Locators" column.
When adding the stock back in, I would like to remove the name.
I haven't currently tried anything, I am unsure of what function I need, what the most efficient way is doing it.
I am not worried about having to research it myself, however I don't quiet know how to word the phrase, or what the formula I need to research is.
I would be grateful for anyone's help!
Kind regards,
Haydn

I believe XLOOKUP will do what you want. Make sure the last parameter is set to -1 to search from the bottom up.

So when you say "...For the last 2 rows" you mean for the same product? If so an xlookup probably won't suit your need for those. And you mentioned you're looking at exhibition lines, but should this search through the whole table or just those instances for the row's particular item?

You may want to search for "running totals" and "Excel". Then you can get running "remaining count" and use FILTER, ARRAYTOTEXT etc.

Can the Remove Stock column have a number greater than 1? If the difference is 2, could the 2 stock removers be the same person? Could you post some relevant screenshots i.e. there's only 1 relevant row in each table (out of 16 rows altogether)? Hiding rows and columns will do the trick.

Here's an attempt for

if the "Quantity @YBS" is less than Quantity Total by 1

In the example, table from Entry_Sheet is named Table1
Here's how the columns are calculated in the second table:
Qty @YBS:
=SUMIF(Table1[Product], [@Item], Table1[Add Stock]) -
    SUMIF(Table1[Product], [@Item], Table1[Remove Stock])

Qty Total:
=TAKE(
    FILTER(Table1[Remove Stock], Table1[Product] = [@Item], 0),
    -1
)

Locators:
=IF(
    ([@[Quantity Total]] - [@[Quantity '@YBS]]) = 1,
    ARRAYTOTEXT(
        TAKE(
            FILTER(Table1[Used By], Table1[Product] = [@Item]),
            -1
        )
    ),
    ""
)

Result:


Since the counts are automatically updated, locators will reflect the additions and removals.
Please test this and let me know if I have understood your purpose correctly. I'll then work on qty 2 etc.
